# How do I remove the last element of a list that is being added in a for loop?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, range

My code:

user_input = input()
hourly_temperature = user_input.split()

for x in (hourly_temperature):
print (x+' ->', end= ' ')

My output (Input is 1 2 3 4 5):

1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 ->

My problem:

I want to remove that last arrow after the 5.

I tried limiting the range of hourly_temperature by doing:

for x in (hourly_temperature[0:]:

but this did not work

Comment: did you try list.pop in https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_ref_list.asp

Comment: `print(' -> '.join(hourly_temperature))` or if they are numbers, `print(' -> '.join(map(str, hourly_temperature)))`

Comment: Hey I finally solved it! I ended up using .join like you suggested in your first example. Thank you!